# keras_contrib - load_all_weights causing ValueError due to optimizer weights

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have a Keras model that with layers `Embedding`, `LSTM`, and `Dropout`, as well as the `CRF` implementation of `keras_contrib`.

I was trying to resume the training of a partly-trained model weights of which I had previously saved. However, when I tried loading a previously trained model via `save_load_utils.load_all_weights` of `keras_contrib`, I received the following error.

> line 108, in load_all_weights:
>
> model.optimizer.set_weights(optimizer_weight_values)
>
> line 113, in set_weights:
>
> 'of the optimizer (' + str(len(params)) + ')')
>
> **ValueError:** Length of the specified weight list (36) does not match the number of weights of the optimizer (0)model.optimizer.set_weights(optimizer_weight_values)

Apparently, the list of optimizer weights have the length 0. In [keras implementation of the optimizers.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/e8fad1be1c1187926a02a35b7f25bc6ab7732699/keras/optimizers.py#L95) it is stated that set_weights *"should only be called after computing the gradients, (otherwise the optimizer has no weights)."*

I was wondering how to somehow manually initialize the optimizer weights so that the model weights I am trying to load can overwrite them. I thought of training the model for a single epoch with a dummy batch of size 1, but are there any other, more elegant ways to achieve this?

[The entire code](https://github.com/ilimugur/short-text-classification/blob/master/kadjk.py) is on Github, but below is the model I trained, to provide a brief reference.

```
# Initialize vocab_size & embedding_weights
# Initialize C, U, N, M, H

model = Sequential()
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, N,
                            weights=[embedding_weights], mask_zero=True,
                            embeddings_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001))
model.add(TimeDistributed(embedding_layer,
                          input_shape=(C, U)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Bidirectional(LSTM(M // 2, return_sequences=True,
                                             kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(GlobalMaxPooling1D()))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(H // 2, return_sequences = True,
                             kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001))))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
crf = CRF(num_tags, sparse_target=False, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001))
model.add(crf)
model.compile(optimizer, loss = crf.loss_function, metrics=[crf.accuracy])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is almost exactly what I mentioned in my question.

I created a small dummy training & validation set, and trained the model for a single epoch so that the network weights are initialized. Then I just loaded the weights from the previous session and continued the training, using `load_all_weights` from `keras_contrib.utils.save_load_utils`. The code sample below roughly depicts the procedure I used.

```
# Initialize real_training_set as a 2-tuple with (input, expected_result)
if load_model_file is not None:
    # Initialize dummy_training_set as a 2-tuple with (input, expected_result)
    model.fit_generator(batch_generator_function(dummy_training_set[0],
                                         dummy_training_set[1], ... ), epochs = 1)
    save_load_utils.load_all_weights(model, load_from_model_file)
model.fit_generator(batch_generator_function(real_training_set[0],
                                             real_training_set[1], ... ), epochs = 1)
```

You may view the actual code on [Github](https://github.com/ilimugur/short-text-classification/blob/f8578a57ab4dcb48a81f89c15a58f25b8d3e0ef7/kadjk.py#L275).

Comment: Setting `include_optimizer=False` in `load_all_weights` also worked for me, without the need to initialise to model on dummy data.